# How can I plot the difference between two series with different tags in Graphite?

Tags: graphite

I have one subset of applications sending metric `LastSentId` with tags `Environment`, `EventType`, `EventSubType`

Example query:

```
groupByTags(seriesByTag('Environment=Prod', 'name=LastSentId'), 'EventType', 'EventSubType', 'max')
```

Example data:

```
00:00:00 | Type1 | SubType1 | 2
00:00:00 | Type2 | SubType3 | 4
00:00:01 | Type1 | SubType1 | 3
00:00:01 | Type2 | SubType3 | 5
00:00:01 | Type3 | SubType4 | 1
```

Another subset of applications sending metric `LastReceivedId` with tags `Environment`, `EventType`, `EventSubType`, 'Application'

Example query:

```
groupByTags(seriesByTag('Environment=Prod', 'name=LastReceivedId'), 'Application', 'EventType', 'EventSubType', 'max')
```

Example data:

```
00:00:00 | App1 | Type1 | SubType1 | 1
00:00:00 | App2 | Type1 | SubType1 | 1
00:00:00 | App1 | Type2 | SubType3 | 2
00:00:00 | App2 | Type2 | SubType3 | 3
00:00:01 | App1 | Type1 | SubType1 | 2
00:00:01 | App2 | Type1 | SubType1 | 1
00:00:01 | App1 | Type2 | SubType3 | 4
00:00:01 | App2 | Type2 | SubType3 | 4
```

I want to plot difference for every row in second dataset with correspoding value from first dataset. Eg

```
00:00:00 | App1 | Type1 | SubType1 | 1 - 00:00:00 | Type1 | SubType1 | 2 = -1
```

with result like

```
00:00:00 | App1 | Type1 | SubType1 | -1
00:00:00 | App2 | Type1 | SubType1 | -1
00:00:00 | App1 | Type2 | SubType3 | -2
00:00:00 | App2 | Type2 | SubType3 | -1
00:00:01 | App1 | Type1 | SubType1 | -1
00:00:01 | App2 | Type1 | SubType1 | -2
00:00:01 | App1 | Type2 | SubType3 | -1
00:00:01 | App2 | Type2 | SubType3 | -1
```

If there is no data for type/subtype in dataset2 - i don't need them in final data. I can write such query in sql:

```sql
SELECT 
  a.minute, 
  a."Application", 
  a."EventType", 
  a."EventSubType", 
  (a.id - b.id) as diff 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      date_part('minute', date) as minute, 
      "Application", 
      "EventType", 
      "EventSubType", 
      max("LastReceivedId") as id 
    FROM 
      "ReceivedData" 
    GROUP BY 
      date_part('minute', date), 
      "Application", 
      "EventType", 
      "EventSubType"
  ) a 
  left join (
    SELECT 
      date_part('minute', date) as minute, 
      "EventType", 
      "EventSubType", 
      max("LastSentId") as id 
    FROM 
      "SentData" 
    GROUP BY 
      date_part('minute', date), 
      "EventType", 
      "EventSubType"
  ) b ON a.minute = b.minute 
  and a."EventType" = b."EventType" 
  and a."EventSubType" = b."EventSubType";
```

but don't understand how to do it in graphite. Or is it even possible. I tried to play with `groupByNodes` but can't get result i wanted.

I know i can do some math with Grafana expressions, but i need it to be pure graphite query for using it in monitoring software.